# How to remove footer from web page? (Update: Not footer... but lines that divs create)

Tags: html, css, footer

So I thought this was a problem with the footer, but it appears to be something that has to do with the divs in the code.

I recreated my project on jsfiddle.  As you can see I have a background image on my site.  If you look closely, you can see a small line running through the background image above the first div box (named `.box2`) and below the second div box (named `.box`).  It almost looks like it is repeating itself.  Why are those lines there and can I remove them?

Here is the jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/VmYZh/3/

Here's the background image itself.

[image]

Added the doe for those who prefer to see it on here over jsfiddle.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<center>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>    
</head>

<body>

<div class="box2">
<img src="logo" width="134" height="60">
</div>

<div class="box">

<h2>Header</h2>

<p>
    Nice paragraph
</p>

<h4>Header</h4>

<ol>
    <li>Blank text</li>
    <li>Blank text</li>
    <li>Blank text</li>
</ol>

<form method="post" action="mailto:name@email.com">

<table id="minimal_table_for_Master_Evan">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p></p>

<input type="submit" value="Save" id="save">
</form>
</div>

</body>

</center>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#minimal_table_for_Master_Evan {
    font-family: "Calibri", "Times New Roman", Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 55%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}

#minimal_table_for_Master_Evan td {
    color: #000;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

html, body {
    background-image:url("ADPBackground.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
p, h2, h4, li {
    font-family: "Calibri", "Times New Roman", Serif;
}

li {
    list-style-position:inside;

}

.box {
    width: 50%;
    margin:30px 50px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border-radius:25px;
    padding: 2em;
}

.box2 {
    width: 50%;
    margin:30px 50px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border-radius:25px;
    padding: 1em 2em;
}

.transbox p {
    margin:30px 40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: `"Also, what is that box... is it a footer?"` Without an image and code, it's like listening to a radio play. :) I wonder what it will turn out to be. :)

Comment: It's a pizza box!.. ;) Anyway, put some of your html code and css so we can see what is your problem

Comment: Added that code... or what I could add.

Comment: There's no way to know what you're seeing or what's not working from what you've posted. Create a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem that doesn't include any of your company's proprietary information. Take a screenshot. Post the screenshot and the (hopefully brief) source code. Then maybe someone can help you.

Comment: I can't post screenshots though cause I have low reputation!

But let me try this.  I think it may be the form getting in the way.

Comment: You can post **code** though...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an issue where your background is repeating at each section so the colours are out of alignment. You can fix this by replacing, background-repeat: repeat; with

```
background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed;
```

Another alternative is to declare the background image only once, not on both html, body that might move your repeat to a different location.